# how to display the url path of attribute in magento

Tags: magento

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level',array('eq'=>2))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',array('eq'=>1))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path');
```

while print $collection i am not getting path

Comment: you should format your post

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this one. Go through this this

```
 $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
                     ->addUrlRewriteToResult();

<?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl($_category); ?>">
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```